# Why does my output contain a 0?

Tags: c++, debugging

I have the following code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int xxx;

     cout << "Enter an integer: 2011 ";

     cin >> xxx;

     cout << "Enter your name: John " ;
     string yyy;
     cin >> yyy; 

     cout << yyy << "entered" << xxx << endl;

     return 0;
 }
```

I expected the output to be:

Enter an integer: 2011 Enter your name: John John entered 2011

However I got the following output:

Enter an integer: 2011 Enter your name: John entered0

- Why didn't I get the expected output?
- Where did the 0 come from? It seems a bit random to me

And a bit of a different question, which has probably been answered before:

- If I want my output to be neatly ordered, as seen below, how would I do this, i.e. what would I need to add to the code?

Enter your integer: 2011

Enter your name: John

John entered 2011

Comment: Sorry, can't tell the difference between the first and second input examples. What are you doing different?

Comment: To clarify, when you ran the code, did you input anything to the lines?, i.e. When the first query came (Enter an integer: 2011), did you actually enter an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things unclear with your code and explanation. I will try to clarify and explain as well as possible.

First of all, the program works fine when I ran it. There were some aesthetic problems, but we will ignore that for now.

So, you have grasped the basics of I/O. When you use **cout**, it outputs something, and when you use **cin**, it is an input operator. Therefore, you must **input** something for it to work, as shown in example below:

```
//Code
int x;
cout <<"Enter an integer: "<<;
cin >> xxx;
```

What should appear on console:

```
>Enter an integer: _
```

(Underscore is cursor). You then should enter an integer

```
>Enter an integer: 231
```

Then, upon pressing enter, the integer you entered, 231, is stored in XXX. Here I have to pause and ask, what is the reason for the "2011" in your code:

```
cout << "Enter an integer: 2011 ";
```

If you think that's the input, it isn't. You have to manually write something in the console window after you run it. If it is something else, it is distracting and...well...useless.

The same principles apply to the **string** component. If you need me to clarify, just let me know.

Also, you really should use spaces to clear up your outputs. Your output text is displayed according to:

```
cout << yyy << "entered" <<< xxx;
```

Instead, you should use:

```
cout << yyy << " entered " << xxx;
```

This gives a neater output that you can read, i.e.

```
>Johnentered231
```

versus

```
>John entered 231
```

**Based on your comment**

Here are some links to get you started:

*Language:*
[C++ Tutorial (follow them sequentially!)](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)

*Compiler*:
[BloodShed Dev](http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html)
[Visual Studio (C++ and more)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718325.aspx)

Comment: Oh, I see. That sounds logical. However, I'm currently using this site: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php. And here I'm not getting the >Enter an integer:_ , am I doing something wrong or is that true for you too?

Comment: Okay, I seriously suggest using a compiler rather than online compiler. There are several, including Visual C++ Express (free), Bloodshed Dev, and Borland. If you are serious about learning and are beginning, I applaud it, but it is better to do it with proper tools. The online compiler does not seem to accept inputs.

Comment: Yes, I agree 100%, but sadly I'm having problems with my C++ express (as you can see in my previous question). But since that's not really part of this question, +1 for this awesome answer. If you could only clarify why it says entered0 (not really important, just for interest), I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It says "entered0" because it doesn't really get an input. What happens is it reads the "cout" and outputs stuff. Then it reads "cin" but doesn't do anything. So, in the variable "yyy", there is nothing, and in "xxx", there is a 0 (the compiler probably puts a 0 into new integers). So, when it outputs the values, yyy contains nothing, while xxx contains 0. So, you see (blank)entered0

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine for me. Also, in order to neatly organize your output, use whitespaces and control characters. If you want your output to look better, I suggest changing the output line of your program to:

```
cout << yyy << " entered " << xxx << endl;
```

Notice the use of whitespaces around "entered". Another thing that peeves me about your code is your lack of descriptive names for variables. Give them something meaningful. For instance, change "xxx" to "number" and "yyy" to "name". It'll save you a lot of headaches in the long run.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: My IDE is Code::Blocks, but what matters is the compiler. I'm using MinGW with GCC 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused between cout and cin. cout is only for output. writing cin after cout and not giving it any input wouldn't take the value "John".

For example,

```
 cout << "Enter an integer: 2011 "; 

 cin >> xxx;
```

should be

```
 cout << "Enter an integer: "; 

 cin >> xxx;
```

then you type in 2011